# How do we return an optional enum value from Swift to Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

We know how to expose Swift enums to Obj-C:

```
@objc enum Animal: Int {
    case Cat, Dog
}
```

But the compiler complains that the following "cannot be represented in Obj-C":

```
func myAnimal() -> Animal? {
    if hasPet() {
         return .Cat
    } else {
         return nil
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Add a `case none` in your enum?

Comment: The error message is expressing the fact. In Objective-C, you cannot represent an Optional value of non-reference type. One possible workaround is adding `nil`-like case to your enum -- `case none, cat, dog`.

Comment: I find an optional enum rather funny. Enums should represent one of several possible cases. Making it optional adds a mother, hidden, state. I would, as suggested by @CodeDifferent, have a `none` case instead. Thou I am not sure if that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional Ints in Swift don't map to a type in Objective-C. The issue is that your myAnimal() method is returning a type that can't be represented in Objective-C.

The way I see it, you have two options...

Option1: Change your method's return type:

```
func myAnimal() -> NSNumber? {
  // method body goes here.
}
```

This doesn't really seem great since in Objective-C you'd have to do something like this:

```
if (myAnimal().integerValue == AnimalCat) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

Option 2: Add a catch-all case in your enum

```
@objc enum Animal: Int {
  case none = 0
  case cat = 1
  case dog = 2

  init(rawValue: Int) {
    switch rawValue {
    case 1: self = Cat
    case 2: self = Dog
    default: self = None
    }
  }
}

// Updated method signature that makes the compiler happy.
func myAnimal() -> Animal {
  if hasPet() {
     return .Cat
  } else {
    return .None
  }
}
```

This way, you can change your method signature to not return an optional, and the compiler will be happy.